# JavaScript arrays - original array modification vs new array creating methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

is there a rule which explains why some methods are modifying original arrays (like splice, push, etc) and other creates new array (like slice, map, concat, etc)?

Comment: No, there isn't, you've just to remember it, or check the documentation before using a method.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is no rule specifying which array methods will modify the callee array or which will return a new array.

They are simple functions, having their own behavior, you just have to remember their behaviors and you always have the web to lookup stuff.